# UNDEFINED VARIABLE ERROR on SELECT on codeigneter is there any better way to do this?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, web, select

Is there any better way doing this without having an error if $personal_info['reg_civil_status'] and $_POST['reg_civil_status'] is empty? Because I'm having an "Undefined Variable Error"

**I'm sorry, I am still a junior programmer, I am new to PHP. Anyways thank you.**

```
                    <b>Civil Status: </b>
                    <select class="controler-1" name="reg_civil_status">
                        <?php 
                            foreach($civil_status_opt as $civil_status_opt){
                                if($personal_info['reg_civil_status'] == $civil_status_opt || $_POST['reg_civil_status'] == $civil_status_opt) {
                                    echo "<option selected='selected' value='$civil_status_opt'>$civil_status_opt</option>";
                                }
                                else {
                                    echo "<option value='$civil_status_opt'>$civil_status_opt</option>";
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
```

Comment: `isset` or `!empty`

Comment: Please do a bit of research before you ask about stuff like this.

Comment: I did, but I cant seem find a similar problem with mine. Thank you btw :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `isset` with ternary operator to avoid error

```
<b>Civil Status: </b>
<select class="controler-1" name="reg_civil_status">
    <?php 
        $reg_civil_status = isset($personal_info['reg_civil_status']) ? $personal_info['reg_civil_status'] : "";
        $posted_reg_civil_status = isset($_POST['reg_civil_status']) ? $_POST['reg_civil_status'] : "";

        foreach($civil_status_opt as $civil_status_opt){
            if($reg_civil_status == $civil_status_opt || $posted_reg_civil_status == $civil_status_opt) {
                echo "<option selected='selected' value='$civil_status_opt'>$civil_status_opt</option>";
            }
            else {
                echo "<option value='$civil_status_opt'>$civil_status_opt</option>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your ternaries (you use `=` instead of `:`).

Comment: Thank you this really helped me. I am new to php sorry :)